# How can I make my keyboard always be at the bottom?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I click on the [`TextField`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) (which opens the keyboard) and click on the button, the keyboard disappears. I want my keyboard to always be at the bottom.

How to achieve what I said?

I've asked about ChatGPT and googled, but still can't solve my problem.

I tried adding [`resizeToAvoidBottomInset`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html) in the [`Scaffold`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) widget, but it didn't work.

My code:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: TextField(
        …
      ),
    ),
    isLoading
        ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
        : Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: …,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: …,
              icon: …,
          ),
  ],
),
```

How can I make my keyboard always be at the bottom?

Comment: What do you mean by "... and click on the button" ? Which button? Present an MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 1) You have not explain what "click on the button" means. Which button?
2) That code is not an MRE since it does not reproduce the example. The code you've posted works just fine.